# How to stop scroll on body AMP

Tags: amp-html

I'm using AMP and I want to open a DIV and stop scrolling I have did many tries, I search and google and I found that if you opened a lightbox AMP added a class `i-amphtml-scroll-disabled` to the body 
So I have made a button who will do the same thing but didn't work

```
on="tap:bodyID.toggleClass(class='i-amphtml-scroll-disabled')
```

but if I change the class will add it to the body but not working with `i-amphtml-scroll-disabled`
is there any way to stop scrolling using AMP

Comment: hi, have you found fix for this?

Comment: I don't think that there is a solution to stop scrolling.